# How to define aliases in the MongoDB Shell?

Tags: mongodb, alias, mongo-shell

I'm using the MongoDB shell and like to define some shortcuts. For example, it would be nice to abbreviate `show databases` with `sd`.

I already managed to add a function `hw()` to the MongoDB shell by adding it's definition to the `~/.mongorc.js`:

```
function hw() {
    print("Hello World.");
}
```

When I type `hw()` in the mongo-shell, it prints out `Hello World.`

---

**Question 1:** Is it also possible to execute the function without having to type the brackets (i.e. `hw` instead of `hw()`)?

I tried to bind the function to variable using anonymous functions, but still I have to type brackets, otherwise the definition of the function is printed out

```
hw=function(){ print("Hello World (anonymous)."); };
```

---

**Question 2:** How can I execute MongoDB commands from within my functions? I tried:

```
function sd() {
    show databases;
}
```

but that gives an error during startup of the MongoDB shell:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier at /home/edward/.mongorc.js:2

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To list databases try :

```
function sd(){
     return db._adminCommand( { listDatabases: 1 } ) 
}
```

Basically you have to run valid javascript here. Remember that you have to run these in context of admin database - runCommand will not be enough - you have to use _adminCommand here.

For other commands see http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/command/

if you would like to get rid of parenthesis there is also a way (you would have to put property on 'this')

```
Object.defineProperty(this, 'sd', {
    get: function() { 
        return db._adminCommand( {listDatabases: 1} )
    },
    enumerable: true,
    configurable: true
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to alias databases in the mongo shell is to use the db.getSiblingDB() command. In the following, imagine you have two MongoDB databases - AmazonSales and EbaySales. Both the databases have a users collection. You can now use the aliases as described below in the Mongo shell, instead of always needing the 'use ' command to switch context

```
var cs = db.getSiblingDB('AmazonSales')
cs.users.count()
cs.users.find({name:'John'})

var r = db.getSiblingDB('EbaySales')
r.users.count()
```